# Laravel test generation with command line

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-artisan

Whenever I try to generate a test case with `laravel php artisan make:test [testName]`, it always `return false` and the test will not be generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that none of your routes specially your main route does not return laravel dd()

Comment: this one was best useful for me

Answer (score 3):

It was my case once, I also had a dd in my web.php in one of my routes. removing it fixed the issue for me.